# how to overlay svg vector graphic over backgroud raster

Tags: python, graphics, svg, png

Does anyone knows how to overlay svg vector graphic over backgroud raster (png) ?

Preferably in python. I've tried cairo and rsvg but I'm getting black bacground after converting svg to png.

```
    img =  cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_RGB24, width, height)

    ctx = cairo.Context(img)

    print 'svg', tmp_svg    
    handler = rsvg.Handle(None, str(svg_data))

    handler.render_cairo(ctx)
    img.write_to_png('/tmp/test.png')
```

After converting svg to png I overlay two png files with python PIL

```
Image.blend(background, overlay, 0.5 )
```

Maybe there is simple solution with overlaying directly background with svg (without svg to png)?

Greets.

Comment: I have similar example, but I've embedded bmp (works with png too) in svg file using svgfig - python lib for work with svg  [link](https://code.google.com/p/svgfig/) . If you are interested I will put example as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image determined at runtime, or beforehand?  If the latter, then you could add an `<image>` element to the SVG that points to your background image.

Comment: How to do so? How to add an <image> element to the SVG that points to your background image?

Comment: Add an `<image>` element to your SVG file.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eHXmQ/